# Lost Commit In Git Merge. Need help explaining

Tags: git, git-merge

I am unable to figure out why would git not merge a certain commit that I have made. Consider the two branches in the image below

[image]

The commit that is of interest is in the red line, 014506c. In this commit, some config properties are changed as shown below.

[image]

Notice the single file that has been changed. This file does not get changed in 33da9d7 but when the merge happens in 746e986, the change is not there. As you can see in the screenshot below, the file is not in the list of changes. . .

[image]

My initial reaction was that perhaps there was a change in 834ff6a that resulted in a merge conflict that was resolved incorrectly. But 834ff6a does not have any change either. See below 
  [image]

I have no clue why this would happen! Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would commit `834ff6a` should contain changes, if changes were done in later commit `014506c`? Why to you refer to `834ff6a`? Most probably commit `6eb292a` had conflicts, which were resolved not properly? Because this merge happened after changes were done...

Comment: I refer to 834ff6a as it is the only commit after the branch was created that had any changes (which could result in a merge conflict) and as it can be seen 834ff6a has no change to that file. So in essence, the blue branch makes no changes to the file in question and there should be no merge conflicts. At least that's what I understand.

Comment: I guess you *are* certain that the file has incorrect content after the merge and it is not just that 014506c undid some changes made earlier on that branch? The question itself does not seem to show that at the moment.

Comment: Ok, now I see, I guess you are right...

Comment: If you do `git diff 33da9d7 6eb292a`, i.e., before and after the merge, are the changes those you see in `834ff6a` plus those in `application-master.properties`? Or is there anything else there? Under normal merge behaviour, that diff and `git diff ec0c80e 834ff6a` should give close to the same results. If they don't, something weird certainly did happen in your merge but I don't see enough information here to say what. If you try the merge again, do you get the same results?